# Ambiguous difference between WordPress stack and Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, wordpress-se

I'm increasingly seeing comments left on Stack Overflow that say things like "Might be an idea to post over at wordpress.stackexchange.com".

After reading into what the WordPress site is for I can't help but think it really doesn't need its own site. If the site is for "developers and administrators", then the only point of difference between it and Stack Overflow is that it's for administrators. But looking over the posts on the WordPress stack the majority are developer based questions.

Looking over the list of Stack Exchange network sites only the WordPress and Drupal sites seem to be in this area of ambiguity. The others are more about users, systems, or just not programming related.

As I haven't been around here that long, I'd like to know why this sub site was created?

I'm struggling to find the logic, as a proposal for a [Joomla](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31698/joomla) stack was declined.

Why do I think this is important? Personally I don't like to navigate between network sites, I'd like to go and contribute in one place. I don't see a problem with Stack Overflow being that place and catering for several platforms.

Also without a clearer clarification more comments like the above, duplicate content across both sites, and distinct content on each site all contribute to devaluing the experience all round. I think this site just adds confusion into the mix for a benefit I'm yet to ascertain.

The nicest things about the network sites is the sub set of more specific tags, but I don't see why this couldn't be introduced into the main Stack Overflow system.

Unless I'm missing something here?!!

Comment: There's rather a lot of duplication on SE sites. For example, most questions on AskUbuntu would also be on-topic at Unix/Linux. However, the Ubuntu site has more users, and they voted to stay separate (although the majority of users on Unix/Linux voted to merge the sites).

Comment: Additionally the questions on [dba.se] would fit well on either [sf] or [so] but there's enough in common that it makes sense to have it well targeted

Comment: http://twitter.com/#!/photomatt/status/14388729011507201

Comment: @Peter, thanks for the cleanup. Abbreviations not allowed I take it then!

Comment: they are allowed, but then they should be introduced at first use. Posts should be understandable outside of the "tribe".

Answer (score 10):

Anecdotally, I'd say that the reason the Wordpress site exists is similar to the reason the Ubuntu site exists, even though there is also a Unix site:

> Dear Stack Exchange Team,
>
> Ubuntu is an end-user operating system
>   used by everyday people who are not
>   typically interested in hacking around
>   a kernel, nor configuring a large
>   collection of tools, projects and
>   packages, nor citing documentation
>   references and command line arguments.
>   The Linux proposal, in comparison,
>   explicitly targets “advanced users,”
>   in which I have no interest.
>
> In short, we need our own space. Thank
>   you.
>
> *Ubuntu Supporter*

In other words, the SO community at large was not all that interested in Wordpress questions, and the Wordpress community was not all that interested in being rebuffed.  Hence the separate site.

Comment: +1 - while I share the OP's sentiment (I'm not happy to see sites break away) this is why the Wordpress SE site exists. You *could* have 90% of the questions on it on SO proper - but Wordpress development and design has become a world for itself, with its own jargon and culture. No denying that.

Comment: @Pekka, regarding the jargon and culture, thats true of almost any framework or platform, jQuery anyone? @Robert, yes I can see that perhaps there are more 'soft' users of Wordpress

Answer (score 8):

Something like this came up before WPSE made public beta, during its public beta and obviously keeps on after it graduated.

> After reading into what the Wordpress site is for I can't help but think it really doesn't need its own site.

If I might ask what is your experience with and interest in WordPress?

You see, for many techies WordPress is just a buzzword. One of those CMS fads that is lately huge or whatever. It is passing interest and they are ok dropping their WP questions into SO mix (process they are used to) and maybe receiving decent answer that will deal with their immediate WP needs.

WPSE attracts and satisfies drastically different group of techies - people that are or want to be WordPress experts. People that specialize in WordPress and get really challenging things done with it - for fun or for a living.

So I'd like to know - how serious you are about WordPress and how much experience with WordPress development do you have to conclude that *doesn't need its own site* ?

> If the site is for "developers and administrators", then the only point of difference between it and SO is that its for administrators.

The difference is that SO is not about WordPress. And WordPress is in desperate need of specialized and high quality informational resource. Apparently this is not a role SO could fill.

> As I haven't been around here that long, I'd like to know why this sub site was created?

Because there was demand and dedication for it, sufficient to carry it through definition and beta.

> I'm struggling to find the logic, as a proposal for a Joomla stack was declined.

I am not aware about situation with Joomla stack, I don't follow Area 51 closely.

I want to note that it would be wrong to compare CMS proposals by "this is CMS, this is also CMS" principle. WordPress is currently massively used CMS that piles up more and more momentum from year to year. Naturally it had best chances to get through definition and beta. And even then is sat in public beta for quite a while.

> Personally I don't like to navigate between network sites, I'd like to go and contribute in one place.

You don't, others do.

> I don't see a problem with SO being that place and catering for several platforms.

I do. I expressed explicitly (and so did other high-ranking WPSE users) that I am not interested in fishing out WP content in larger and more generic site.

> Also without a clearer clarification more comments like the above, duplicate content across both sites, and distinct content on each site all contribute to devaluing the experience all round.

WPSE provides terrific WP experience. I don't think I heard much of same about WP experience on SO before or now.

> I think this site just adds confusion into the mix for a benefit I'm yet to ascertain.

Could you please formulate more clearly what you are confused about?

As highly active user and community moderator at WPSE I can confidently say that I observe very few users being confused about it.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with most of what you say, but whenever I troll around Wordpress.SE, I see pure PHP and CSS questions that *should* be over on SO because they are not specific to WP. It hurts me a bit to see those not getting migrated. Just as a side note. Other than that, every question that needs deep knowledge in WP and understanding of WP specific jargon, has a good home on WP.SE, and it seems to be working fine for them.

Comment: @Pekka yep, I get what you mean. You see, WPSE is much newer site but it's already on regular community moderation diet. We are only building up mass of users, sufficient for community moderation to work fast and efficient. It is almost impossible to see answer gather enough close votes naturally, but stream of incoming questions is way past the point where each passed before moderator's eyes.

Comment: @Rarst yeah. I expect that is going to work out over time.

Comment: @ Rarst I've been developing on Wordpress for about 2 years and fully delve into the darker underbelly, including filters, custom most types, custom write boxes and custom widgets. So my knowledge commitment or interest is not a passing fad. I use the platform daily.

Comment: @Rarst Regarding 'fishing out' content, thats what the taxonomies are for, hardly taxing to click a tag to view the wordpress content on SO. As for formulating more clearly what I am confused about, yes where should wordpress questions go, especially if they are more PHP based than the normal codex function based questions. Is the wordpress stack the catchall I guess? Regarding "WPSE provides terrific WP experience" - yes that may be so, and I don't doubt your hard work in making that the case, but what about the people who search for wordpress on SO?

Comment: @added because skiiers and snowboarders both go downhill fast on snow, they are the same communities and should be grouped together? Also, the world is full of duplication (even cross-site) and some duplication is healthy: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: @Jeff depends if they are asking questions about snow!! :)

Comment: @Jeff, hmm nice article. Maybe then a set of 'We found these similar posts on Wordpress Stackexchange' when viewing wordpress tagged questions could be good. Embraces the difference and connection rather than having two seemingly separate sites, with ambiguity.

Comment: @addedlovely WordPress-specific questions should go on WPSE, that's what it was created for. Some PHP questions might make sense on WPSE, when it deals with specifics of WP functions, debugging and such.

Comment: @Rarst, I've made an account, I'll be kicking around. See you there :)